# Spark filter specific letter/letters from each word

Tags: scala

I want to extract specific letter/letters from each word of a string.

Suppose the string is:

```
val myString = "I want to extract letters form each word of the string"

val splitString = [I, want, to, extract, letters, form, each, word, of, the, string]
```

Now if I want to get only a,e,i,o,u from each word (if the word contains any of them), how could I do that? What would be the syntax?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: The question is tagged java, python and apache-spark. However, from the question itself it looks like you use pure scala - which is it?

Comment: yes its pure scala

Comment: My code

val wordsFile = sc.textFile("myFile.txt");
val splitWords = wordsFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "));

Comment: For my above string the output should be, 
[i, a, o, ea, ee, o, ea, o, o, e, i]  only the vowels(if any) in a word.

Comment: see my answer below @SanTuhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter out vowels only then

```
val wordsFile = sc.textFile("myFile.txt")
val splitWords = wordsFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")) 
        .map(word => word.toLowerCase.replaceAll("[aeiou]", ""))
//res0: Array[String] = Array(, wnt, t, xtrct, lttrs, frm, ch, wrd, f, th, strng)
```

If you want to filter in vowels only then

```
val wordsFile = sc.textFile("myFile.txt")
val splitWords = wordsFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")) 
        .map(word => word.toLowerCase.replaceAll("[^aeiou]", ""))
//res0: Array[String] = Array(i, a, o, ea, ee, o, ea, o, o, e, i)
```

Comment: val extractVowel = splitWords.map(vowels => vowels.toLowerCase.replaceAll("[^a,e,i,o,u]","").filter(x => x!= "").sorted);
val mapWord = extractVowel.map(word => (word, 1));
val maxvowel = mapWord.reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b).collect.maxBy(_._2);

This code just works fine. But when I tried to print the key only with the following line of code, then I got an error said "value keys is not a member of (String, Int)"

maxvowel.keys.collect().foreach(println);
Any idea to fix it??

Comment: thats because `maxvowel` is a Tuple2 and not a Map. So there is no such keys method on Tuple2. And maxBy returns only one Tuple2 value. you can just do `println(maxvowel)`

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh. I got the Tuple with two elements like (ae, 9087). But I need to print only 'ae' not (ae, 9087). I can do that with map but I can not do it with a tuple. Actually I am very new in scala, so got some problems with very basic things.

Comment: Accessing the elements of Tuple values is done by using _1 _2 and so on. _1 will give you the first element and _2 would give you the second element. And since you have Tuple2[String, Int], you can access the first element i.e. `ae` by doing `println(maxvowel._1)` . By the way you have already used it in maxBy function call. didn't you notice that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 myString.split(" ").toList.map(x => x.replaceAll("[^aeiou]", "")).filter(x => x != "")
```

String is first split, converted to list and each element is mapped to new element by replacing the vowels. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your help but I need to extract the vowels from the words(if any), not remove them.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, you can simply take the opposite regex. Answer edited

Answer (score 0):

```
def vowels(s: String) = s.toLowerCase.replaceAll("[^aeiou]", "")

myString.trim.split("\\W+").map(vowels)
```

The `vowels` function extracts the vowels from the word. This can be replaced with whatever processing you need.

`trim` removes leading/trailing spaces and `split` divides the string into separate words allowing for punctuation.

`map` just applies `vowels` to each resulting word.